# Bootstrap 4 Spacing Breakpoint Confusion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Seems like a lot of people have had some confusion with Bootstrap's breakpoints and spacing utils, and after going through their questions I still have no resolution to my issue. I'm trying to apply left & right padding to my element when the screen is anything larger than xs - otherwise, just give it px-2.

```
<header class="entry-header container-fluid px-2 px-xl-5">
```

However, this doesn't work. My code will just default to `px-2` and ignore `px-xl-5`. If I delete px-2, then px-xl-5 spacing will work. How can I get different spacing on these different screen sizes? It seems like such a simple question but for some reason I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I'm trying to apply left & right padding to my element when the
> screen is anything larger than xs"

Then you'd use `px-sm-5`, not `px-xl-5`, because `px-sm-*` means **"small (576px) and up"**, while `px-xl-* means **"extra large (1200px) and up"**

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/rsLM6hARlx)